# MongoDB replica set not starting

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb replica set server is failing on start. followin is my config file:

```
# mongod.conf

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /home/gurbakhshish/dbKey/mongodb.key

replication:
  replSetName: "nm-prd-dbs"
```

is this config correct. I dont have the issue if i comment security section of config file

Comment: Seems good, did you invoke `rs.add("host:port")` for every member in your cluster in a mongod command line?

Comment: the cluster is already set up and working, i just turned Auth and keyfile on  this and when i try to restart the servers they doesn't come up

Comment: Does mongod has rights on /home/gurbakhshish? By default, it doesn't have the rights; this file might need to be deployed in /etc.